# how to show links inside a block

Tags: blocks

```
function custom_block_view($delta = '') {
$brands = $brand->getChildrenCategories();
      foreach ($brands as $node) { #print_r($node);
        $items[] = array(
            'data' => t($url = Mage::getUrl($brand->getUrlPath()).'.html')
            #'data' => t($node['name'])
        );
      }

$block['content'] .= theme('item_list', array(
          'items' => $items
              ));

    }
```

I use this code to display items in a block. I want this to be a link but was not able to achieve it. The output is shown below:

[image: snap]

Comment: Please use l() function instead of t().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function in place of [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) (which is a string translation function):

```
$url = Mage::getUrl($brand->getUrlPath()).'.html';
$link = l('Link Title', $url);
```

If the URL is external you'll also want to provide that information in the `$options` parameter:

```
$link = l('Link Title', $url, array('external' => TRUE));
```

Comment: i really feel intimidated.It was so simple i couldn't find it while googling. :(. Thanks Clive